# converting a text.file into a dictionary and facing too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm new in programming and python
I tried to convert my text file to a dictionary

I've tried this

```
dictionary = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\WIEN2k.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(" ")
        dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary
```

but I got the error

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 with open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\WIEN2k.txt") as file:
>         3     for line in file:
>   ----> 4         key, value = line.strip().split(" ")
>         5         dictionary[key] = value
>         6 print(dictionary)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

can anyone help me regarding this error?

Comment: This doesn't look `pandas` related, if not, remove the tag. Also it's impossible to answer this question without your actual text file

Comment: There is more than one space in the line you are trying to split in line 4. Look at your data. Remember lines man have trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than 1 whitespace in your line in file. And when you're trying to split. You get 1, 2, 3, 4, and more values but you're expected that you have only 2 value after splitting

```
dictionary = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\WIEN2k.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        values = line.strip().split(" ")
        if values:
            dictionary[value[0]] = values[1:]
print(dictionary)
```

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html more about `string.split()`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @BoarGules and @frankegoesdown, there is more than one space in the line. If you rather want the first word in your lines to be the key and the rest to be the value of your dict, you can do:

```
dictionary = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\WIEN2k.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(" ", maxsplit=1)
        dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary)
```

To debug such issues, you can just store the intermediate result and print it, like:

```
dictionary = {}
with open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\WIEN2k.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        fields= line.strip().split(" ")
        print('list {l] has {n} elements'.format(l=fields, n=len(fields))
        key, value = fields
        dictionary[key] = value
print(dictionary)
```

And execute the code or run it in the debugger. From the output above, you will see, that some of your lines result in lists with more than two elements and that right after printing those line, you get the error you mentioned.